# Adding to a list using Java stream within the filter method

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> map1= new HashMap<>();
map1.put(1, true);
map1.put(2, true);
map1.put(3, false);
map1.put(4, true);
map1.put(5, false);

Map<Integer, Integer> map2= new HashMap<>();
map2.put(1, 1);
map2.put(2, 2);
map2.put(3, 3);
map2.put(4, 4);
map2.put(5, 5);
List<Integer> valids = new ArrayList<>();
map2.values().stream().filter(value-> map1.get(value) ? valids.add(account) : false);
```

When I try to output the values of the list `valids` it returns an empty list. Why is it so? Does the reference of the list change when doing the `stream` operation?

Note :I am able to add to it using the `collect()` method.

Comment: Don't do that. A filter function is supposed to filter. Not to have side-effects. Learn how Streams work and what are the correct and incorrect things to do. You don't have any terminal operation on the stream, so the your last line is a noop: nothing is ever filtered. The javadoc, and the hundreds of tutorials about streams, are your friends.

Comment: As a side note, `map1.get(value) ? trues.add(account) : false` is the same as `map1.get(value) && trues.add(account)`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct, because using `filter` for adding an item to list, that defeats purpose of `filter`.

You should terminate `filter` pipeline by collecting result. The stream here is Open and hence can not flush result to list;

Use:

```
map2.values().stream().filter(map1::get).forEach(trues::add);
```

Or if you want to use that way then close stream by a collector function

```
map2.values().stream().filter(value-> map1.get(value) ? trues1.add(value) : false).count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.

A `filter` method is supposed to `filter` a stream, not add something to some other list. Also, your stream doesn't have any terminal operation - its a wrong approach.

Change it to using `collect` as you mentioned. It would be more readable & maintainable that way.